# Java spring bean wont load xml config file

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I want to use some values that are stored in a config file. Im trying to load in the config file and use it with a bean. Im new to spring and beans so im not really sure the best implementation for this. But i want to use the values as constructor arguments to the bean. I have a packet beans with the xml file beans in it. And in the same map "src/java/main" is the other packet with the xml file credentials.config.

/TwitterDownload/src/main/java/TwitterProjectNTS/beans/beans.xml qualified name for beans

/TwitterDownload/src/main/java/TwitterProjectNTS/TwitterDownload/credentials.config qualified name for credebtials.config

```
<import
    resource="/TwitterDownload/src/main/java/TwitterProjectNTS/TwitterDownload/credentials.config" />

<bean id="TwitterConfigurationStartupSettings"
    class="">
    <constructor-arg
        value=""></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg
        value=""></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg
        value=""></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg
        value=""></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I have read many articles about this but have not got a good understanding for how to really get this to work. Seems like there are many ways to read and use the values from the file.

Grateful for answears

Comment: First, you should put your xml config files in the `src/main/resources` directory, so it would be better, and could even help.

And you will have to make sure your `beans.xml` file is loaded when your server starts

Comment: I created a resources file but i still cant get it to work. Errormessage: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [/TwitterDownload/src/resources/credentials.config]
Offending resource: class path resource [TwitterProjectNTS/beans/beans.xml]

Comment: You have to put them both in the `src/main/resources` folder

Comment: Now I have changed the code so i load in a properties file as a bean property and got it working. However now im using a absolute path. I cant get it to work with a relative path. I have tried to even put the in the same package but the program still cant find the properties file.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Maybe your properties file aren't properly loaded by the IDE, as it happens sometimes with Eclipse